# Can't load module php_mssql on wamp in Win 64 bits

Tags: php, sql-server, 64-bit, wamp

I moved from a pc **32bits** to a **64bits** pc. I've copied the entire "c:/wamp" (wamp version 2.2) folder to the new pc, installed the services, but the **php_mssql** module has not loaded.

Is there a way to run the php_mssql + php 5.3 on windows 7 64 bits?

Apache error log:

```
PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.3.13/ext/php_mssql.dll' - Não foi possível encontrar o módulo especificado.
```

The dll is at the correct place, but I don't know why, the error log still complains about the dll file.

[image: php_mssql is there]

*Note: We can't migrate to **sqlsrv** at this time because there is lot of apps using php_mssql.*

Comment: Your SQL Server? 2012? 2014?, also, it probably is 64 bits also, i remember reading somewhere you will need to download 64 bit driver for php on 64bit machine, also native client 2008 or somethign

Comment: So you didn't upgrade WAMP to 64-bit, just using 64-bit OS with same previous 32-bit WAMP install? Do you have both 32-bit and 64-bit c++ 2008/2011 redistributes installed?

Comment: - I've tried wamp 64bits some minutes ago and I got another error: is not a valid Win32 application. 
- About the c++ red. I have the 2008 x86 and 2010 x86 and 64.

Comment: @MarkNg I copied the ntwdblib.dll to system32 and sysOW64 too.

Comment: I actually upvoted your question as I have no idea as you can't migrate to sqlsrv at this time.

Comment: yesterday I made the same procedure on XP mode (virtual pc) and worked well...it's very sad because this corroborate my theory that is impossible run php_mssql in a 64 bits windows.